# Rails: AJAX Datatables Button to open Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

I am in the process of updating datatables to AJAX. There are Action buttons, some redirect to other pages and the one I am stuck with opens a modal. I am working in a Decorator file.

Here is the code that works with without modal buttons:

```
def dt_actions
    links = []
    links << h.link_to(h.content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-search") + " View", h.training_provider_client_path(context[:current_provider], object), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs m-r-5px")

    links << h.link_to(h.content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-pencil") + " Edit", h.edit_training_provider_client_path(context[:current_provider], object), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs m-l-5px")
```

This is the line of code that is pre-AJAX that I can't seem to format as above:

```
a.btn.btn-success.btn-xs.m-l-5px.clients-issue-certs-modal-link> href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#choose-course-modal0" data-client-id="#{client.id}"
      => fa_icon 'graduation-cap', text: 'Issue Certificates'
      = fa_icon 'chevron-right'
```

Also for reference, here are the two top links pre-AJAX, that I was able to convert:

```
    = link_to training_provider_client_path(client.owner, client), class: '' do
      = fa_icon 'search', text: 'View'
    - if policy(client).edit?
      = link_to edit_training_provider_client_path(client.owner, client), class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' do
        = fa_icon 'pencil', text: 'Edit'
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: The question is how would you write the `a.btn.btn-succes.......` code to be added like the rest in `links << h.link_to...`?

Comment: Hi @arieljuod, I suppose yes, in that format but with the modal data-target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```rb
h.link_to(h.content_tag(:i, "", class: "graduation-cap") + " Issue Certificates" + h.content_tag(:i, "", class: "chevron-right"), "#", class: "btn btn-success btn-xs m-l-5px clients-issue-certs-modal-link", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#choose-course-modal0", "client-id" => client.id})
```

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod, that code seems to show the right link, though now, it seems that the modal itself if not opening with the AJAX datatable.

I will try to look into why this is the case. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I understand you are showing this icon after an AJAX request and the modal is something handled by something like bootstrap, right? if so, you may need to trigger the bootstrap JS related to modals after you update the DOM with new content

Comment: Thanks again @arieljuod -- was missing an initializer to get the JS to load